# From an array of objects, extract one property and build a string with them

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

The way I'm doing it is to save that properties into an array and after that to join them.

Original array of objects:

```
const objArray = [ { prop: "a", etc: 1}, { prop: "b", etc: 2}, { prop: "c", etc: 3} ];
```

First step, save the values of property `prop` into an array:

```
const firstStep = objArray.map(a => a.prop);
```

Second step, concatenate them into a string:

```
const secondStep = firstStep.join(' + ');
```

This works fine but I'm thinking if there is a better/shorter method to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't much, but you can chain the operations together, there's no need to save the intermediate result in a variable first:

```
const result = objArray
  .map(a => a.prop)
  .join(' + ');
```

```js
const objArray = [ { prop: "a", etc: 1}, { prop: "b", etc: 2}, { prop: "c", etc: 3} ];
const result = objArray
  .map(a => a.prop)
  .join(' + ');
console.log(result);
```

Other than that, I don't think it's possible to implement the logic in a shorter fashion.